# AttributeError : module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool_'

Tags: python, tensorflow, numpy

VirtualboxのUbuntuにおいて
Pythonの対話モードで

```
import tensorflow
```

と入力したところ

```
AttributeError  : module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool_'
```

というエラーが出てきます。

"import numpy"と入力した際には何もエラーが出てきませんでした。
どのようにしたらエラーを防げるか教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

以下の記事の様に良くある間違いでしょう。

カレントフォルダとか、Pythonのimport対象フォルダパスのどこか、本物のnumpyがあるよりも先に検索されるフォルダのどこかに、`numpy.py`というファイルを作ってしまったのだと思われます。
それがimportされているので、質問のエラーが発生しているのでしょう。
紹介記事の中にもあるように、よく使われそうな名前でファイルを作るのは止めましょう。

[Pythonで module 'XXX' has no attribute 'XXX' が出た時の解決方法](https://qiita.com/tonosamart/items/df5155bb79694fa64206)
[PythonでエラーのAttributeError: module ‘xxx’ has no attribute ‘xxx’が起きた場合の対処方法](https://code-schools.com/python-attribute-error/)
[くだらない理由でAttributeError: module ‘numpy’ has no attribute ‘core’](https://tono-n-chi.com/blog/2016/09/numpy-attribute-error-2147/)
[How to fix AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'square' closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48235169/9014308)

[Pythonでimportの対象ディレクトリのパスを確認・追加（sys.pathなど）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-import-module-search-path/)